# What Is The Basis Of This Durood? Is This Durood Authentic?

Tags: hadith, authenticity, salawat

This Holy Durood Shareef is found in many mosques of the Ahle-Sunnah who are **not** innovators. I want to know is there any basis of this Durodd in any authentic Hadith collection? This is the Durood I am talking about:-

[image]

Comment: It is recorded by Ţabarānī.

Comment: I couldn't find an authentic reference with that exact wording, but a somewhat similar one.

Comment: @IbneKhan - So, it is authentic?

Comment: https://islamqa.info/en/answers/202162/how-sound-is-the-hadeeth-whoever-sends-blessings-upon-me-eighty-times-on-friday-his-sins-will-be-forgiven-for-eighty-years is this the same one?

Comment: @valikaze125 - The link you quoted states that the narration associated with this Durud is weak (i.e. the narration of reciting this Durud 80 times on the day of Friday). It does not state that this Durood is itself not authentic.